# Smooth css bounce in effect

Tags: css, css-animations

https://hemmerle.com/creations/earrings/ How could I create this kind of bouncing effect in the caroussel with CSS? I tried to modify animate.css bounceIn effect but I couldn't get the animation to look like the website

```
@keyframes bounceInRight {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }

  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: add your html too

Comment: Please share the html code or share the fiddle link.